# Controls in url "0" - HTMLYouTubeVideoElement - Popcorn.js 1.5.6

Tags: javascript, youtube, popcornjs

Using Popcorn JS 1.5.6 and the recommended HTMLYouTubeVideoElement (preferred to the depreciated Popcorn.youtube) to display an embedded YouTube video, I came across a minor issue. Using, for example:

```
var media = Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement( "#video" );

media.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/CxvgCLgwdNk?controls=0";

var pop = Popcorn( media );

pop.play();
```

I get the correct video displaying, however the controls are showing. Notice the "?controls=0" in the url. A value for 0 in controls should make the video controls hide. This works if you go to the link directly.

The problem is with the player vars in Popcorn.HTMLYouTubeVideoElement. On line 6270 of [popcorn-complete.js](http://cdn.popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.js):

```
playerVars.controls = playerVars.controls || impl.controls ? 2 : 0;
```

`playerVars.controls` is set to `"0"`, which evaluates to `true`, and therefore `playerVars.controls` is updated to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem, as can be seen from:

```
playerVars.controls = playerVars.controls || impl.controls ? 2 : 0;
```

is that Popcorn sets the controls value to 0 if no value is supplied by in the URL. So, removing "controls=0" from the url hides the controls.

This is confusing because going directly to the URL "http://www.youtube.com/embed/CxvgCLgwdNk" would show the controls, whereas Popcorn would hide them.

Testing for:

```
playerVars.controls === "0"
```

in HTMLYouTubeVideoElement could be used to fix this confusion.